# Checking if signal handler isn't default

Tags: c++, linux, signals

Is it possible to check from other thread, if signal function was already called? (i.e default signal handler isn't the default one)
    signal(SIGTERM, signal_handler);

Comment: If it were my problem, I would consider setting up some global shared state that the signal hander updates when it executes and then check that from a separate thread. Anything having to do with signals and signal delivery can be tricky to build and debug due to all the corner cases.

Comment: Actually I cannot change the code and I'm writting tests.
And I cannot call signal_handler function directly, so everyting is a litte bit messed up.

Comment: I think your question is unclear then if that's the answer to it. It could be read two ways: How can tell if a signal hander has been called?  How can I tell if a signal handler has been installed?

Comment: `<
old_handler = signal(some_signal, newhandler);   
    if(old_handler != default_handler)   
        signal(some_signal, old_handler);  
>`
And with that knowledge, i wouldn't say it cannot be called.  
I was expecting some is_default_handler function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always get the current signal handler via `signal()` or `sigaction()` (they return the previous handler before applying the new one, see mans).

After you get it, you can compare it to whatever you want. E.g. if you're talking about the real default signal handler you could compare the current one to `SIG_DFL` (or probably you'll have to set the handler to `SIG_DFL`, then again to another handler, storing what was associated with `SIG_DFL`).